# New configuration files for X

Tags: xorg

Something happened to my Kubuntu 14.10 system that caused it to lock up, and when I rebooted I just got a black screen.  I was able to log in on a virtual terminal and also was able to reboot in recovery mode.  But neither of those got me to the graphical interface, and I kept getting a segfault at 0x50. I've tried startx and a few other things, but I always end up with that segfault or something equally useless.

Since I haven't been able to restore a working X system (KDE, actually), I think my best bet would be to reinitialize X entirely with a fresh set of configuration files, while leaving the rest of my system undisturbed.  Is there a way to do that?